# If $A \in SL(d,\mathbb{Z})$ does the same hold for $A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, integer-lattices

If I consider an element $A \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, then I have that $A^{-1}\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I can see this because the inverse of $A$ is obtained by movin the coefficient of the metrix or changing their sign.

Does the same hold for an element of $SL(d,\mathbb{Z})$. I cannot convince myself of that. Could you explain this to me or give ma counterexample?

I cannot convince myself of these even thinking of lattice automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^d$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cofactors of $A$ are obtained by performing ring operations on the entries of $A$. The inverse of $A$ is then the matrix of cofactors of $A$ divided by the determinant of $A$. Since the determinant of $A$ is $\pm 1$, all of the entries of $A^{-1}$ will lie in $\mathbb{Z}$ and the determinant will be the same as that of $A$.

Check out [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix) for more information.